# Need Proper Guidance

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce

I am finding a way or package where I can create website where member can sell them electronic (downloadable) product and all money will store into the website account. After defined amount they can transfer to them registered PayPal account.

Example: [Theme Forest](http://themeforest.net/)

I would really appreciate if any free script is available or I can integrate with any popular CMS (wordpress, joomla) without security issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension that allows your members to do just that. [I found it here](http://joomdonation.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=41&Itemid=40). I haven't used it personally, but it sounds like what you are looking for.

Good luck!

Cynthia

Comment: Thanks for your reply Cynthia. However I need to know more about it. Meanwhile if you know something better which can give me output almost similar to themeforest then please let me know.